# How to set haproxy session and static page?

Tags: session, haproxy, static-files

I have these two problems:

1. HAProxy session

   Login into administrator management page for Jira/Confluence by load balancer, can't login.
   If login into each server, it can login into administrator management page.
2. HAProxy Static page

   Jira load balancer IP can't show regular CSS page. But they are good if access to different servers.
   So the reason will be the configuration about static in HAProxy.

---

Add `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend jira
    bind :::8080 v4v6
    # acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    # acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    # use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             jira

frontend confluence
    bind :::8090 v4v6
    # acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    # acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    # use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             confluence

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# backend static
#    balance     roundrobin
#    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend jira
    balance     roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
    server jira1 [IP1]:8080 check cookie jira1
    server jira2 [IP2]:8080 check cookie jira2

backend confluence
    balance     roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
    server confluence1 [IP3]:8090 check cookie confluence1
    server confluence2 [IP4]:8090 check cookie confluence2
```

Comment: 1. You can try cookie based sticky session, if you tried one please add it here we can suggest why it's not working.
2. Just a quick question, are you trying to host static pages something like how we do in `nginx`? If that's what you are trying I can say for sure that HAPoxy doesn't support static pages except for error pages. But feel free to add your comment if I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: @BinaryBullet I added the config content for HAProxy. Now static file issues has been fixed after delete browser cache. And I can login into the systems successfully, too. But it will logout automatically after refresh page sometimes. Do you know why?